# Why does unable to find locations based on Google Maps geocoding geometry.bounds but possible by geometry.viewport in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-maps, geocoding

I have the following document with location resided in Wellington New Zealand:

```
 {
    "name": "Wellington New Zealand",
    "location": [
        174.77623600000004,
        -41.2864603
    ]        
}
```

I'm using google geocode to get Country bounds for string "New Zealand" like the following:

```
geocoder.geocode('New Zealand', function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

The result is the following:

```
{
"address_components": [{
    "long_name": "New Zealand",
    "short_name": "NZ",
    "types": ["country", "political"]
}],
"formatted_address": "New Zealand",
"geometry": {
    "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
            "lat": -29.2313419,
            "lng": -175.831536
        },
        "southwest": {
            "lat": -52.61941849999999,
            "lng": 165.8694369
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "lat": -40.900557,
        "lng": 174.885971
    },
    "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
    "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
            "lat": -34.1295578,
            "lng": 179.0625357
        },
        "southwest": {
            "lat": -52.61941849999999,
            "lng": 165.8700053
        }
    }
},
"place_id": "ChIJh5Z3Fw4gLG0RM0dqdeIY1rE",
"types": ["country", "political"]
```

As you can see from the output above there is `geometry.bounds` and `geometry.viewport` objects. I'm trying to find documents based on `bounds` like the following:

```
db.collection.find({
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            $box: [
               [bounds.southwest.lng, bounds.southwest.lat],
               [bounds.northeast.lng, bounds.northeast.lat]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this query does't return any documents but when I use `viewport` instead I get documents well:

```
db.collection.find({
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            $box: [
               [viewport.southwest.lng, viewport.southwest.lat],
               [viewport.northeast.lng, viewport.northeast.lat]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Could you explain why I can't get documents by using `bounds` and can by using `viewport` and how should I do it right?

**UPDATE:** I've explored that `geometry.bounds` is [bounds](http://jsbin.com/bomogojopa/1/edit?html,output) and `geometry.viewport` is [viewport](http://jsbin.com/xadutacizi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Could explain what is defference between `geometry.bounds` and `geometry.viewport` and what should I use?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MongoDB, but I would guess the issue is the fact that the ne-longitude is smaller than the sw-longitude. Maybe it helps when you add 360 to the ne-longitude.

Comment: I don't little understand what do you mean. Colud you provide short example please?

Comment: `bounds.getSouthWest.lng` is `165.869` and `bounds.getNorthEast.lng` is `-175.831` . The longitude of Wellington is `174.776` . When the DB calculates mathematically(that's my assumption) the longitude of Wellington must be greater than the southWest-longitude and smaller than the NorthEast-longitude(which isn't the case, because 174 is larger than -175). When you add 360 to the NorthEast-longitude the LatLng will still point at the same location, but now the longitude is larger.

Comment: my suggestion(just a guess): use  `$box: [
               [bounds.southwest.lng, bounds.southwest.lat],
               [bounds.northeast.lng+360, bounds.northeast.lat]
            ]`

Comment: I  need common case, maybe it's possible to detect wrong `lng`, `lat` and correct these?

Comment: the lat and lng are correct, when something is wrong it's the calculation of the DB

Comment: @Dr.Molle thanks for the help it works fine. But MongDB uses the bounds -180 inclusive and 180 non-inclusive. So if I add 360 to the ne-longitude I'll get `-175.831536 + 360 = 184.168464`

Answer (score -1):

30.335098600000038, 59.9342802 is not within your (New Zealand) bounds. It's in [middle-of-nowhere-Iran](https://www.google.com/maps/place/30%C2%B020'06.3%22N+59%C2%B056'03.4%22E/@30.4961623,59.6706084,8z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0).